# How do I prevent WordPress plugin updates deleting a .git file?

Tags: wordpress, git, .htaccess, plugins

I'm managing my plugin updates on a WordPress website using git. However, whenever I hit 'update' on a plugin it deletes the `.git` file that is stored in the plugin folder, so I can't track the changes that have been made in the update.

I understand updating a plugin removes the old plugin files, but how do I prevent WordPress from removing this specific `.git` folder? If I tighten the file permissions it causes an update error.

NB: I know I could initialize a git repo in the parent `plugin` folder, which would track files in all of the plugins at once, but I'm wanting a separate repo for each specific plugin, hence the `.git` file residing just within the plugin folder.

Is there a hook or filter I can use to alter the update process? Or an htaccess rule I could use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think better will be if you want to track changes done in new version then you can do it this way.

**step 1**:  create a seprate branch in your plugin git folder name it `new_version` or something.

**step 2**: replace all file of that branch with new updated plugin code files.

**step 3**: now merge that branch with your new branch.

you will see all chnaged file 
and you can check those changes with `git diff`